# ckeditor image plugin fine configuration

Tags: ckeditor

It is possible to configure image plugin dialog to change defaults (for example, change alignment from  to right, HSpace to some value, etc) without actually changing javascript code of the plugin?

The cmbAlign select is in the image.js and seems to be in some long and nested object structure, specifying UI.

What is the right place to introduce the change?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should take a look at the CKEditor Javascript API which allows you to modify the editor without having to change the original javascript code, see

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/index.html